# SQL Server: implicit data type conversions chart

Tags: sql-server, implicit-conversion

As far as I can tell, according to [this chart](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx), an implicit conversion from VARBINARY to DATE should be OK. However, when I try the following code, SQL Server responds with "Implicit conversion from data type varbinary(max) to date is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query."

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CONVERSION_TEST](
[mydate] [date] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO


declare @bin varbinary(MAX) = NULL
insert into conversion_test values (@bin)
```

I'm running this on SQL Server 2012 (version 11.0.3128).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found this connect  post:

[Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/321586/datetime2-cannot-be-casted-implicitly-to-varbinary-in-column-alterations)

Which has the following statement from Microsoft:

> Posted by Microsoft on 05/03/2008 at 13:23 After some serious
>   discussion, we believe that the current design is good especially
>   given it's not an interesting scenario and we already support explicit
>   conversion for the new date/time types.
>
> On the other hand, we also think that it's not necessarily a good
>   thing given we supported too many implicit conversions on existing
>   types. Conversion to/from binary is a dangerous thing, and requiring
>   explicit conversion makes sense. It's unfortunate that ALTER TABLE
>   behavior is tied to implicit conversion, but you can always work
>   around it by creating a new column, issue an update, and then drop old
>   column if that's main scenario you worried.
>
> So if no strong objection, we're going to do the followings:
>   **- Fixing the BOL to indicate that there's no implicit conversion support from binary/varbinary to new date/time types**
>   - Close this as 'By Design'
>
> thanks

So it would appear that they decided to disallow this implicit conversion but not update that diagram.

Comment: So, it is indeed a documentation bug :( Too bad, we could really use that feature.

Comment: Yeah, I've left feedback on the article in the hope that they'll update it, but I'm not holding my breath.